# Landsat 8 geometry of image

Tags: geometry, landsat, landsat-8

I'm trying to find actual geometry of the Landsat 8 image.

I retrieve Landsat data from ONDA service using EODAG. Onda provides Landsat 8 images in TIF files in epsg:4326. And it looks so:

[image]

Also, in response data EODAG and Onda provides field "geometry", but it is a geometry of the image's bounding box, not of the image.

I found that there is tiles grid called `WRS` that contain geometry tiles of image according to image's `PATH` and `ROW` params. I got it from the site https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-shapefiles-and-kml-files. It looks so:

[image]

I downloaded WRS2 descending (https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-wrs-2-descending-path-row-shapefile) and filter geometries by path and row of my image, but got this:

[image]

I tried again with another file (WRS 2 Scene Boundaries KML File https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-wrs-2-scene-boundaries-kml-file) and again got close but wrong geometry:

[image]

Does anyone have other ideas how to find correct geometry of the Landsat 8 image? At least maybe there is some easy way how to calculate polygon from image mask? Because black pixels in first pictures are just 0 pixels and I can make an image mask easily.